# Find two groups that give a cyclic decomposition of $G=\mathbb{Z}_4 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Let $G=\mathbb{Z}_4 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$. Find two distinct pairs of subgroups of G such that each pair gives a cyclic decomposition of G with no subgroup of the second pair equal to either subgroup of the first pair:

Ok, well $G=\mathbb{Z}_4 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2=\{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1),(2,0),(2,1)(3,0),(3,1)\}$

Are my two distinct pairs going to be: $\{(0,0),(1,0),(2,0),(3,0)\}$ and $\{(0,1),(1,1),(2,1),(3,1)\}$ ?

I've done cyclic decomposition for *permutations* many times, but how does one do cyclic decomposition of a direct sum? Thanks!

Comment: user26857 - I actually figured it out today. Thanks! Also, I will be more mindful of upvote good answers - thanks for letting me know.

Comment: "Are my two distinct pairs going to be..." Clearly not since you don't give two pairs. Note also that the second subset is not a subgroup.